# Proper way to pass scope to imported class

Tags: javascript

Say I have a class such as the following.  Is passing `this` for the imported class appropriate?  Or is there a better way to access the scope of the parent?

```
import Fruit from 'fruit'

export default class Banana {
  constructor () {
    this.color = 'yellow'
  }
  let length = new Fruit(this).getLength()
}
```

```
export default class Fruit {
  constructor(scope) {
    this.parentScope = scope 
  }

  getLength() {
    if (this.parentScope.color == 'yellow') {
      return 5
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: In this case, so you really need to pass the scope when all the public properties of the class are already available through its object. How would passing scope benefit?

Comment: @Saksham Could you show me how to access the public properties from Fruit?

Comment: `let length = new Fruit(this).getLength()` is invalid where it is in your first example, so it's difficult to provide any advice.

Comment: It's also unclear to me what you mean with "scope of the parent", because "scope" has a specific meaning but that doesn't apply here. But I agree with frodo that you probably want inheritance.

Comment: @FelixKling Invalid ? It definitely works... its just improper I would say, but yes I think inheritance here is the answer.

Comment: You cannot have a variable declaration inside a class body but outside a method declaration. It’s a syntax error.

Comment: @FelixKling Okay yes youre right my bad should of made the example better.

Answer (score 0):

Yessir, there is a better way, it's called class inheritance. You want to make your banana class extend the fruit class. That way, they both are the same object, and your banana inherits all the methods and properties of the fruit class.

```
export default class Banana extends Fruit {
```

https://javascript.info/class-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are a few concepts which you are missing which I have corrected making least changes to your code

```
class Fruit {
  getLength(color) {
    if (color == 'yellow') {
      return 5;
    }
  }
}

class Banana {
  constructor() {
    this.color = 'yellow';
    let length = (new Fruit()).getLength(this.color);
    alert(length);
  }
}

let aFruit = new Banana();
```

The main part is that instead of passing the whole scope, you may pass just the color of the Banana object.

If you really have something to do with the parent scope, try extending the child class from parent.